# My css wont show when i start the server up

Tags: css

So my main.css don't load for some reason and i don't know why, so when i try to inspect it showes Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.css, its probably some dumb mistake but i cant find it :(

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use "./stylesheets/main.css" instead?

Comment: i tried that before and still the same response :/

Comment: Where is the file located on the server? There is the html and then a folder called stylesheets?

Comment: yes there is one index page and file is located in public/stylesheets/main.css

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Zl98u maybe this prtsc is help full

Comment: I see you are using nodeJS to serve the static files. Are you using express? If yes you should check your app.static calls.

Comment: var express = require("express");
var app = express();


app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **app.static** call from your server file. Your nodeJS server is not serving static files. You should do:

```
app.use('/stylesheets',  express.static('public/stylesheets');
```

Comment: Thank you i just saw i miss that line <3